# Convert Access SQL To VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am in need of converting this Access SQL Query to a VBA Query ->

```
SELECT informationTable.userID, 
ConcatRelated('itemSold','[informationTable]',"userID='" & [userID] & "'") AS NameOfItemSold
FROM informationTable
GROUP BY informationTable.userID;
```

I tried ths VBA

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT informationTable.userID,
 ConcatRelated('itemsold','[informationTable]','userID= ' & Chr(34)  & [userID] & Chr(34) & ') AS NameOfItemSold 
Into CRInformationTable
FROM informationTable 
GROUP BY informationTable.userID;")
```

but I get an error of

> A RunSQL action requires an argument consisiting of an SQL statement

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? The only thing you are showing us is the SQL statement. You combine the SQL statement with VBA code, as VBA is not a type of query.

Comment: You have to turn the SQL statement into VBA `string` type variable and there is specific syntax for that.

Comment: Also, can't 'run' a SELECT sql. SELECT sql is used to set a RecordSource object or form/report RecordSource property. Only action sql can be run - UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT INTO. You can Open a SELECT query object. But why open query object? Why not create report using the query as RecordSource?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - see my edit.  I failed to realize I omitted my VBA syntax

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh - See comment by June7. Also, I am wary of `ConcatRelated`. I bet Access doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: @June7 & ScottHoltzman - It is a Select Into statement.

Comment: Sorry, completely missed the Into keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing. Assuming userID is number type field, see if this works for you:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT DISTINCT informationTable.userID, " & _
    "ConcatRelated('itemsold','[informationTable]','userID=' & [userID]) AS NameOfItemSold " & _
    "INTO CRInformationTable FROM informationTable;")
```

If userID is text type:

```
"ConcatRelated('itemsold','[informationTable]','userID=" & Chr(34) & "' & [userID] & '" & Chr(34) & "') AS NameOfItemSold " & _
```

Instead of Chr(34):

```
"ConcatRelated('itemsold','[informationTable]','userID=""' & [userID] & '""') AS NameOfItemSold " & _
```

Comment: [userID] is a short text type field.

Comment: Ooops! Did you find my extra ) typo? Edited answer again.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this nifty tool many times with great success.

**Creating the form**

The form just needs two text boxes, and a command button. SQL statements can be quite long, so you put the text boxes on different pages of a tab control.

Create a new form (in design view.)
Add a tab control.
In the first page of the tab control, add a unbound text box.
Set its Name property to txtSql.
Increase its Height and Width so you can see many long lines at once.
In the second page of the tab control, add another unbound text box.
Name it txtVBA, and increase its height and width.
Above the tab control, add a command button.
Name it cmdSql2Vba.
Set its On Click property to [Event Procedure].
Click the Build button (...) beside this property.
When Access opens the code window, set up the code like this:

```
    Private Sub cmdSql2Vba_Click()
        Dim strSql As String
        'Purpose:   Convert a SQL statement into a string to paste into VBA code.
        Const strcLineEnd = " "" & vbCrLf & _" & vbCrLf & """"

        If IsNull(Me.txtSQL) Then
            Beep
        Else
            strSql = Me.txtSQL
            strSql = Replace(strSql, """", """""")  'Double up any quotes.
            strSql = Replace(strSql, vbCrLf, strcLineEnd)
            strSql = "strSql = """ & strSql & """"
            Me.txtVBA = strSql
            Me.txtVBA.SetFocus
            RunCommand acCmdCopy
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Using the form**

Open your query in SQL View, and copy the SQL statement to clipboard (Ctrl+C.)
Paste into the first text box (Ctrl+V.)
Click the button.
Paste into a new line in your VBA procedure (Ctrl+V.)

[image]

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html